# Is there any way to plug in a type-??? without causing a LBrace error??? (CSS) Code I am trying to use is here:

Tags: css

Code just changes the color of Pokemon Showdown's typeless button.

```
.movemenu button.type-??? {
    background: #201E1E;
    border-color: #68A090;
    color: #68A090;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;

}
```

Comment: The code works with any other type (ex: type-placeholder), but when using ??? the code breaks, and as the element is already defined as ??? within the server I cannot change it, meaning I need a way for it to read ??? as text rather than as a way to request URls

Comment: Are you saying the HTML has a class of type-???

Comment: Yeah, the HTML does have a class type of type-???